# logger is not working using logback.xml in websphere server 8.5

Tags: spring, websphere, logback

logger is not working using logback.xml.

developed project in RAD that have several project like WAR,Schema and EAR  built with Maven and deployed into Web sphere server8.5.

using log4j.properties file my logger is working proper but i don't want to use it.

dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and logback file:

```
<configuration debug="true">    
 <appender name="STDOUT_ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">  

            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">  

                    <level>ALL</level>   

            </filter>

            <encoder>

                    <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%contextName] %X{Context} %-5level [%thread][%logger{36}] - %msg%n

                    </pattern>

            </encoder>

    </appender>
```

```
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT_ERROR" />

</root>
```

The output log shows:

```
[8/27/14 5:53:41:961 EDT] 00000090 MessageDispat I org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'memberService': initialization completed in 1000 ms 
[8/27/14 5:53:41:961 EDT] 00000090 servlet I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [mbr-ear] [/MemberService/] [memberService]: Initialization successful. 
[8/27/14 5:53:43:148 EDT] 00000090 SystemOut O 05:53:43.148 [WebContainer : 2] DEBUG c.w.m.d.nasco.ws.MemberServiceEP - <<<<<<<<<<< Entering Profile Web service >>>>>>>>>>> 
[8/27/14 5:53:43:148 EDT] 00000090 SystemOut O 05:53:43.148 [WebContainer : 2] INFO c.w.m.d.nasco.ws.MemberServiceEP - <<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>> 
[8/27/14 5:53:43:148 EDT] 00000090 SystemOut O 05:53:43.148 [WebContainer : 2] WARN c.w.m.d.nasco.ws.MemberServiceEP - <<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>
```

Even i have tried with file appender but file is also not creating.

Comment: Can you post logback debug output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Magic Wand.

Now its working.

```
<dependency>


                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

            </dependency>

             <dependency>


                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>                 

            </dependency>

            <dependency>


                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>

                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>

            </dependency>
```

this dependency i have given into EAR project pom file
now its working fine.
thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear you made it working ;) My bad is that I did not ask you to see Maven EAR plugin configuration...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use slf4j over log4j, you are missing some JAR's in your classpath. Please add this into Maven configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

That way slf4j is going to intercept log4j logs and redirect it into logback. Of course, you can also add other logging facades such as commons-logging and java.util.logging:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes i have tried for root level all.It didn't work.  :(

Comment: Where is your logback.xml stored? If you use Maven for building, try to put it into src/main/resources folder, because that way it will be correctly picked up by logback.

Comment: i have stored same place src/main/resources and tried with WEB-INF/logback.xml.

Comment: when i deployed project WAR file into tomcat server then its logger working perfect...

Comment: Can you deploy WAR on WAS and see what's happening? Also, are you packaging logback.jar into EAR? Because, if no logback.xml is present in classpath, logback will use default configuration, which is console appender with DEBUG level. So, I suspect no logback JAR is present in EAR. I have successfully used logback on WAS 8 with EAR containing multiple WAR and EJB-JAR project, and my logback.xml was stored in a separate JAR that was packaged into EAR as utility JAR.

Comment: No not working,Now there is no logger message's on the console.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your problem - you want to replace log4j with logback. Please see my updated answer if it will work for you.

Comment: I have created jar file of my logback.xml file and given the dependency of jar module to ear module .It didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to deploy WAR on WAS 8.5 that was working on Tomcat? Can you verify that slf4j JARs are added into EAR as utility JAR's. Please check your EAR/WAR structure and describe it here.